# See how many people are needed for a site to go in beta/commit stage

Tags: feature-request, area-51

On the sidebar for a Area51 site, you see this section which shows what percent of people needed to launch the site have committed. There should be a way to see how many people are still needed to launch the site. A mockup of what this could look like is below.

[mockup http://cl.ly/1ReZ/content](http://cl.ly/1ReZ/content)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There aren't a set number of people. It depends on how much reputation on existing SE sites the person committing has that determines how much they count towards the 100%.

Comment: And it's currently stuck at 90% because the code for the next stage hasn't been rolled out yet I think (but it's coming).

Comment: Well, then it could show how much rep is needed to go to the next stage.

Comment: @Henri It's not that simple. It's a fairly complicated formula that takes several factors into account.